# Как найти самое часто повторяющееся слово в тексте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dict, count

Напишите программу, которая считывает текст из файла (в файле может быть больше одной строки) и выводит самое частое слово в этом тексте и через пробел то, сколько раз оно встретилось. Если таких слов несколько, вывести лексикографически первое (можно использовать оператор **`<`** для строк).

В качестве ответа укажите вывод программы, а не саму программу. 
Слова, написанные в разных регистрах, считаются одинаковыми.

> Использовать надо циклы, списки, словари. 
> Не использовать `lambda`, регулярные выражения и доп.модули, и все что надо импортировать.

В файле, который дается для обработки нет осмысленных слов, знаков и т.п. 
Там по сути наборы букв разделенные пробелами и в разном регистре, например:

```
gtdFtd jy k dyygGTDHj kdH DJDJ.
```

У меня получился вот такой код. Вроде по логике должно работать. Но ответ не принимает как правильный. 
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем моя ошибка.

```
with open ("C:\\Users\\iRU\\Desktop\\Dataset\\dataset_3363_3.txt", 'r') as inf:
    s = inf.read().replace('\n', ' ').lower().split()
words = {}
words[s[0]] = 1
k = 0

for i in range (0,len(s)-1):
    if s[i] in words:
        k+=1
        words[s[i]] = k
    else:
        words[s[i]] = 1

word = list(words.keys())
word_count = list(words.values())
max_word_count = 0
min_word = ''

for i in range(len(word_count)-1):
    if  word_count[i] > max_word_count:
        max_word_count = word_count[i]
        min_word = word[i]
    elif word_count[i] == max_word_count:
        if word[i] < min_word:
            min_word = word[i]

print(min_word,max_word_count)
```

Comment: Тут много вопросов к самому заданию, почему нельзя какие-то вещи типа рег. выражений, если принимается только ответ, а не программа, а также как учитываются слова, важен ли регистр, 'привет.' (с точкой) считается ли за слово 'привет' или за отдельное слово 'привет.'.

Comment: Уберите, пожалуйста, русские слова из кода, сделайте имена переменных из английских слов. Читать гораздо легче, понятнее будет.

Comment: Владислав, это не javascript. split() в python делит на слова.

Comment: Да, удалил комментарий, не заметил split в начале.

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов нельзя какие-то вещи потому, что надо решить задачу с использованием материала предыдущих лекций. На самом деле осмысленных слов в тексте нет. там просто наборы букв разделенные пробелами.

Comment: @Danny спасибо буду иметь в виду и писать на английском

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
text = '''
Существует культ Питона, называемый "Дзеном Питона" (The Zen of Python).
Автором этих постулатов считается Тим Пейтерс.
Основные постулаты:
Красивое лучше, чем уродливое.
Явное лучше, чем неявное.
Простое лучше, чем сложное.
Сложное лучше, чем запутанное.
Плоское лучше, чем вложенное.
Разреженное лучше, чем плотное.
Читаемость имеет значение.
Особые случаи не настолько особые, чтобы нарушать правила.
При этом практичность важнее безупречности.
Ошибки никогда не должны замалчиваться.
Если не замалчиваются явно.
Встретив двусмысленность, отбрось искушение угадать.
Должен существовать один — и, желательно, только один — очевидный способ сделать это.
Хотя он поначалу может быть и не очевиден, если вы не голландец. [1]
Сейчас лучше, чем никогда.
Хотя никогда зачастую лучше, чем прямо сейчас.
Если реализацию сложно объяснить — идея плоха.
Если реализацию легко объяснить — идея, возможно, хороша.
Пространства имён — отличная штука! Будем делать их побольше.'''

lst_no = ['.', ',', ':', '!', '"', "'", '[', ']', '-', '—', '(', ')'  ]   # и т.д.
lst = []

for word in text.lower().split():
    if not word in lst_no:
        _word = word 
        if word[-1] in lst_no:
            _word = _word[:-1]
        if word[0] in lst_no:
            _word = _word[1:] 
        lst.append(_word)

_dict = dict()
for word in lst:
    _dict[word] = _dict.get(word, 0) + 1

# сортируем словарь посредством формирования списка (значение, ключ)
_list = []
for key, value in _dict.items():
    _list.append((value, key))
    _list.sort(reverse=True)

# печатаем первые 10 самых используемых слов
print('Первые 10 самых используемых слов:')
for freq, word in _list[0:10]:
    print(f'{word:>10} -> {freq:>3}')

print('\nили так: (с условием, что длина слова > 4- букв) \n')
_dict = {(i, lst.count(i)) for i in lst}
_list = []

for word, kol in _dict:
    _list.append((kol, word))
    _list.sort(reverse=True)
    
for freq, word in _list[0:20]:
    if len(word) > 4:
        print('{0:10} {1}'.format (word, freq))
```

---

---

**Update**

> Подскажите, для чего используется _ перед dict и list?

`_word`, `_dict`, `_list` - это обычные имена переменных,
такие как `my_word`, `my_dict`, `my_list`.

> Также вопрос почему длина слова от 4?

Это просто шло вам бонусом, если вам не надо - убираю.

```
text = '''
Напишите программу, которая считывает текст из файла (в файле может быть 
больше одной строки) и выводит самое частое слово в этом тексте и через 
пробел то, сколько раз оно встретилось. Если таких слов несколько, вывести 
лексикографически первое (можно использовать оператор < для строк). 
В качестве ответа укажите вывод программы, а не саму программу. 
Слова, написанные в разных регистрах, считаются одинаковыми.

Использовать надо циклы, списки, словари. Не использовать lambda, 
регулярные выражения и доп.модули, и все что надо импортировать. 
В файле, который дается для обработки нет осмысленных слов, знаков и т.п. 
Там по сути наборы букв разделенные пробелами и в разном регистре, 
например: gtdFtd jy k dyygGTDHj kdH DJDJ.

У меня получился вот такой код. Вроде по логике должно работать. 
Но ответ не принимает как правильный. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем моя ошибка.

Подскажите, для чего используется _ перед dict и list? 

`_word`, `_dict`, `_list` - это обычные имена переменных, 
такие как `my_word`, `my_dict`, `my_list`. 

Также вопрос почему длина слова от 4? - это просто шло вам бонусом, 
если вам не надо - убираю.
'''

lst_no = ['.', ',', ':', '!', '"', "'", '[', ']', '-', '—', '(', ')', '?', '_', '`'  ]   # и т.д.
lst = []

for word in text.lower().split():
    if not word in lst_no:
        _word = word 
        if word[-1] in lst_no:
            _word = _word[:-1]
        if word[0] in lst_no:
            _word = _word[1:] 
        lst.append(_word)

_dict = dict()
for word in lst:
    _dict[word] = _dict.get(word, 0) + 1

# сортируем словарь посредством формирования списка (значение, ключ)
_list = []
for key, value in _dict.items():
    _list.append((value, key))
    _list.sort(reverse=True)

# самое частое слово в этом тексте
print(f'самое частое слово в этом тексте -> `{_list[0][1]}`, использовалось `{_list[0][0]}` раз.')
```

Comment: Подскажите, для чего используется _ перед dict и list? Также вопрос почему длина слова от 4?

Comment: @ElenaVasileva я добавил обновление, проверьте его.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
# открыли файл, прочитали, привели текст к нижнему регистру, убрали
# знаки пунктуации, получили список слов (цифры и иже не учитываем)
with open(r'C:\sandbox\input.txt') as f:
   lst = f.read().lower().translate(
      str.maketrans('', '', '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~—')
   ).split()
# составляем словарь подсчёта (падежи, к слову, также не учитываются)
res = {x:lst.count(x) for x in lst}
print(max(res, key=res.get)) # первое из наиболее часто встречающихся
```

Comment: Лучше использовать `string.punctuation` вместо рукописной строки

Comment: @dIm0n перечитайте внимательней задание. Перечитали? Если можно было использовать `string`, задачу можно было бы вообще решить так: ```collections.Counter(pathlib.Path(r'C:\sandbox\input.txt').read_text().lower().translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation + '—')).split()).most_common()[0]``` И кстати, дефис и тире различны, если вы не в курсе.

Comment: Думаю, под дополнительными модулями имеются в виду нестандартные питоновские модули. Так что такое решение тоже подойдёт

Comment: @dIm0n нет, к сожалению не подойдет. Как я написала в самом начале задачу надо решить с использованием for, if, while, словари, списки.

Comment: @ElenaVasileva стоит уточнить в вопросе, что нельзя использовать никакие модули, если вы это имеете в виду. `string.punctuation` -- это просто строка, она не нарушает правила *"решить с использованием for, if, while, словари, списки"*

Comment: @dIm0n наверное мне стоило уточнить, что в файле, который дается для обработки нет осмысленных слов, знаков и т.п. Там по сути наборы букв разделенные пробелами и в разном регистре, например: gtdFtd jy k dyygGTDHj kdH DJDJ. Чтобы использовать string.punctuation, необходимость выполнить import. Этого делать нельзя.

Comment: @ElenaVasileva используйте кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1180338/edit) для редактирования вопроса

Comment: @dIm0n спасибо, исправила.